# Can't seem to find the resolution An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException'

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am totally new at any kind of coding and trying to figure out how selenium Webdriver works. I found some videos from one of the online teachers but while I was following that using C# can't seem to find the resolution for the exception below, I tried different selector types from CssSelector to Xpath but wasn't able to figure out what exactly is going wrong. Thank you in Advance.

An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.InvalidSelectorException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: invalid selector: Compound class names not permitted

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;

namespace WebDriverDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Users\samanat\Documents\Testing\Drivers");
            driver.Url = "http://google.com";
            var searchBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib"));
            searchBox.SendKeys("Global Khulna.com");
            //Searching Global Khulna
            driver.FindElement(By.Name("btnG")).Click();
            //Clicking Search button
            driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

            var imagesLink = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("q qs"));

            //driver.FindElement(By.TagName("More")).Click();
            //Clicking More
            //driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("q qs")).Click();
            //Clicking Images

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

within:

```
var imagesLink = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("q qs"));//WRONG
```

When finding a element by ClassName the search string cannot have spaces within it. You will need to find another way to call the element. Most devs use CSS patterns such as:

```
var imagesLink = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span.q.qs"));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi RokingWatson, thank you for your answer. After replacing that I found the following error.            An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"span.q.qs"}

  (Session info: chrome=48.0.2564.116)

  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)

Comment: @Saibot Did you happen to check the CSS of the element by right clicking on the element and inspecting it? The CSS may not be the exact same as the class name. You might want to check out [SeleniumHQ](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) for learning how to call elements.